# What python pip does to make me able to just write the package name to start it after installation?

Tags: ubuntu-18.04

For example, if I do a `sudo -H pip3 install youtube-dl`, once installed I can right away use `youtube-dl` in my terminal.

What pip did to achieve that ?

Answer (score 3):

The package's [setup.py](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/setup.py) configuration sets these parameters:

1. `entry_points = {"console_scripts": ["youtube-dl = youtube_dl:main"]}`
2. `scripts = ["bin/youtube-dl"]`

If Python's setuptools recognizes the first parameter, it generates a Python script named `youtube-dl` that imports youtube_dl and calls the youtube_dl.main() function.

Older versions which use the second parameter will instead copy an existing script already provided by the developers (which does [the exact same thing](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/bin/youtube-dl).

In both cases, the Python script is placed in `/usr/local/bin/` (for sudo pip) or `~/.local/bin/` (for pip --user), and since these directories are in your $PATH environment variable, the shell will look in them when trying to find the command you entered.